# Ajax and Fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm using an Ajaxify plugin with Wordpress and I'm trying to get fancybox (or any lightbox script!) to load when an image is clicked. 
The fancybox plugin works fine without using the Ajaxify plugin but doesn't load at all with the Ajaxify plugin enabled. 
I'm guessing I've got to somehow recall the script but I'm not too sure how to go about this. 
I did try to add a 'no-axify' class to the fancybox link but to no avail:

```
jQuery('.fancybox').each(function(){
    jQuery(this).addClass('no-ajaxy');
});
```

I even purchased the Pro version which is less functional than the free version and the support hasn;t helped either.

Any ideas will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

in the function.php, add this code: (make sure the action priority should be less than 10. I used 9.)

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_test_function', 9);
function my_test_function(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/mine.js', array( 'jquery' ));
}
```

the /js/mine.js has simple code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.fancybox').addClass('no-ajaxy');
});
```

so, once you view source of your site, the mine.js should be included before the ajaxify.js

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It starts to bring up the lightbox but then goes to a seperate page just displaying the image... so its as if the fancybox function isnt properly activating.

Comment: And I'm using this plugin: [link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajaxify-wordpress-site/)

Comment: You should make sure that adding 'no-ajaxy' class is called before the ajaxify initialized.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Still not working, the fancybox starts to open but then opens the image on a new page. Going to have to scrap this idea I think. Thanks anyway.